# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.core.runtime.RegistryFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, sdo, data-objects

I'm trying to use DataObjects in Java:

```
DataFactory factory = DataFactory.INSTANCE;
```

in one java Project using:

```
import commonj.sdo.DataObject;
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.core.runtime.RegistryFactory
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getRegistry(InternalPlatform.java:671)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getExtensionRegistry(Platform.java:867)
 at com.ibm.wsspi.sca.extensions.ServiceProviderRegistry.loadServiceProviders(ServiceProviderRegistry.java:167)
 at com.ibm.wsspi.sca.extensions.ServiceProviderRegistry$1.run(ServiceProviderRegistry.java:88)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:202)
 at com.ibm.wsspi.sca.extensions.ServiceProviderRegistry.getServiceProviders(ServiceProviderRegistry.java:86)
 at com.ibm.wsspi.sca.extensions.ServiceProviderRegistry.getServiceProvider(ServiceProviderRegistry.java:101)
 at com.ibm.ws.sca.resources.loader.ClassLoaderRegistry.<clinit>(ClassLoaderRegistry.java:59)
 at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
 at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
 at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.container.impl.ContainerImpl.<clinit>(ContainerImpl.java:356)
 at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
 at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
 at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.container.impl.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:70)
 at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.container.Container.<clinit>(Container.java:111)
 at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
 at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
```

Comment: sounds like good ol' classpath issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Process Server?   I'm pretty sure  com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.container.impl.ContainerImpl is a Process Server class...

Comment: Yes I'm but I solve the problem putting the classes under packages org.eclipse.emf.ecore.sdo.sample.client and org.eclipse.emf.ecore.sdo.sample.dms

Answer (score 0):

I think the application is based on EMF SDO?

Instead of Java application, you may run your application as a Eclipse application in your IDE, because the application require OSGi bundle loading mechanism to load the required bundle (i.e. org.eclipse.core.runtime) in the runtime.

Comment: I'm trying to run in Webphere Application Server 7.0, is the target Server. Do we need any special bundle on WAS?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue when trying to instantiate the BOFactory class from JUnit. I was able to resolve it by adding `org-eclipse-equinox-registry.jar` files to my projects, along with the SDO jar files.

[image: Adding JAR files to Project]

See also: [Junit : Exception while creating BOFactory instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239589/junit-exception-while-creating-bofactory-instance)