# Junit : Exception while creating BOFactory instance

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am trying to setup JUnit framework on IID8.5. But when I am trying to run simple JUnit testcase I am receiving runtime error. (**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.core.runtime.RegistryFactory**)

I am using JUnit4.[Please find attached image showing project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yagdb.jpg)

`**Code in BOUtils.java`**

```
package com.wf.utils;
import com.ibm.websphere.bo.BOFactory;
import com.ibm.websphere.sca.ServiceManager;
import com.ibm.websphere.sca.Service.*;

public class BOUtils {

/**
 * @param args
 */

public static void createBusinessObject()
{
    System.out.println("Create  Business Object");
    BOFactory boFactory = (BOFactory) new    ServiceManager().locateService("com/ibm/websphere/bo/BOFactory");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}

**Code in JunitTest.java**

package JunitTest;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import com.wf.utils.BOUtils;
import org.junit.Test;


   public class JunitTest extends TestCase {
   @Test
   public void testPersistCust()
  {
     System.out.println("testPersistCust");
     BOUtils.createBusinessObject();
  }
}  


**Exception Stack Trace**
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.core.runtime.RegistryFactory
at       org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getRegistry(InternalPlatform.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getExtensionRegistry(Platform.java:867)
at com.ibm.wsspi.sca.extensions.ServiceProviderRegistry.loadServiceProviders(ServiceProviderRegistry.java:167)
at com.ibm.wsspi.sca.extensions.ServiceProviderRegistry$1.run(ServiceProviderRegistry.java:88)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:202)
at com.ibm.wsspi.sca.extensions.ServiceProviderRegistry.getServiceProviders(ServiceProviderRegistry.java:86)
at com.ibm.wsspi.sca.extensions.ServiceProviderRegistry.getServiceProvider(ServiceProviderRegistry.java:101)
at com.ibm.ws.sca.resources.loader.ClassLoaderRegistry.<clinit>(ClassLoaderRegistry.java:59)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.container.impl.ContainerImpl.<clinit>(ContainerImpl.java:343)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.container.impl.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:70)
at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.container.Container.<clinit>(Container.java:111)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.manager.impl.ServiceManagerImpl.<init>(ServiceManagerImpl.java:68)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1325)
at com.ibm.websphere.sca.ServiceManager$InstanceCreator.create(ServiceManager.java:53)
at com.ibm.websphere.sca.ServiceManager$InstanceCreator.access$000(ServiceManager.java:43)
at com.ibm.websphere.sca.ServiceManager.<clinit>(ServiceManager.java:73)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
at BOUtils.createBusinessObject(BOUtils.java:14)
at JunitTest.testPersistCust(JunitTest.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.executeMethodBody(TestMethodRunner.java:99)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runUnprotected(TestMethodRunner.java:81)
at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runMethod(TestMethodRunner.java:75)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.run(TestMethodRunner.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.invokeTestMethod(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.run(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:35)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner$1.runUnprotected(TestClassRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner.run(TestClassRunner.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:45)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.RegistryFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:419)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:345)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:609)
... 47 more
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Let me know if any addtional information is required.

Regards,
RD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That exception tells you that a certain class is not available to the JVM you are running this within.

The simple answer: then start searching that class ... and you could find this [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgeclipseequinoxregistryjar.htm) - where you can download various eclipse related JARs.

Thus: try what happens if you org-eclipse-equinox-registry.jar to your classpath.

( This [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650040/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-eclipse-core-runtime-registryfactory) might contain an explanation of what is going on )

Comment: Thanks adding org-eclipse-equinox-registry.jar files to Project(s) Build Path along with IID runtime environment resolve the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked out this way. One can not be sure there, as those eclipse framework things might have other dependcies, too.